# How to include plugin without activation?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, activation

I need to include plugin in my WordPress theme without plugin activation.
I have these lines:

```
include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/math/class-constrained-array-rounding.php';

include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'class.jetpack-user-agent.php');
```

and

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tiled-gallery', plugins_url( 'tiled-gallery/tiled-gallery.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_style( 'tiled-gallery', plugins_url( 'tiled-gallery/tiled-gallery.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '2012-09-21' );
```

I think I need to use function `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `plugin_dir_path` to include these files, but I'm confused.

I'm new in WordPress. Can somebody suggest a solution to this problem? :)

Comment: The Question would be why? Please give more details. Maybe another way would be better...

Comment: Thank you, I create theme for a client and I need to include plugin for WP gallery. It should be in theme files, without plugin activation.

Comment: Something else to bear in mind: plugins are loaded earlier than themes are which gives them a chance to hook into more filters etc. during start up. I don't think there's a problem with those, but in general there's a chance a plugin won't work properly when loaded later with a theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/pluginName/'` will give you the absolute path to the directory of the plugin.

**EDIT After comment**

Plugins are plugins, theme files are theme files. Lets not confuse the two.
You cannot copy a plugin in the theme directory - because stuff does not work like that.

After careful editing you can include the plugin as part of your themes options.

### Lets make an example:

1. I want to include the hello dolly plugin in my theme. So I copy hello.php into my themes directory like so: `themes/mytheme/include/plugins/hello.php`.
2. In order to load this file ("plugin" - but its not really a plugin anymore) I need to `require_once` the `hello.php` file like so:

   ```
   define('mytheme_inc_path', TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/');
   define('mytheme_inc_url', get_template_directory_uri(). '/includes/');
   require_once mytheme_inc_path. 'plugins/hello.php';
   ```

   a. If I have a more complex "plugin" then the code will be like this:

   ```
   require_once mytheme_inc_path. 'plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php';
   // because the plugin deserves its own directory
   ```

   Within the `myplugin.php` you will enqueue the required scripts and styles like so:

   ```
   function mytheme_plugin_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_script('tiled-gallery',
           mytheme_inc_url . 'tiled-gallery/tiled-gallery.js',
           array('jquery')
       );

       wp_enqueue_style('tiled-gallery',
           mytheme_inc_url . 'tiled-gallery/tiled-gallery.css',
           array(), '2012-09-21');
   }

   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_plugin_scripts');
   ```

### Caution

- Be sure to remove unwanted 'plugin' `hooks` (filter, activation/deactivation or otherwise).
- Be sure to remove all other `actions` except those that you really require

## Conclusion

If you did some research in script/style enqueue how-to's you'd know that plugins (that are stored in `wp-content/plugins` or `wp-content/mu-plugins` use a bit different functions to retrieve absolute/relative path and uri. Like so:

[Function Reference/wp enqueue script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_Scripts_Only_on_a_Plugin_Administration_Screen)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to include plugin files in my theme files. Plugin should be a part of my theme. I guess I should use get_template_directory_uri() instead of plugin_dir_path, but I can't write it in a correct way, I'm new in php. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: @Aineko how about now?

Comment: Oh thank you very much, aifrim! Now it's all ok. It works!

Comment: Then you should chose it as the right answer =D You are welcome.